# Is s3 bucket region really matter if CloudFront is enabled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I plan to create a `s3` bucket and link it to a CloudFront distribution. CloudFront will cache the content across all regions. Is the `s3` bucket region really matter in this case? If I choose Sydney as the bucket region and most of the users are from Asia, does it give a bad performance for users? (CloudFront will make sure the content are cached in Asia).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are purely serving content from Amazon S3, then you are correct that users will not be impacted by the bucket location once the data is cached.

The first time that somebody requests a particular object from a particular edge location, it will be retrieved from S3 and stored in the edge cache (plus region edge cache). So, there will be a minor difference in speed for the initial fetch. Once it is cached, there will be no difference.

Please note that Amazon CloudFront is populated on request ("pull"), rather than all content being loaded in every edge location ("push").